# Does Sort() method in C# use recursion?

Tags: c#, sorting, quicksort

I have read recently that C# uses Quicksort algorithm to sort an array. What I would like to know whether C# uses recursive approach or iterative approach?

What I have found is [this link and it looks to me that they use iterative approach](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,78c62950ae211cd3,references). I am just wondering whether it is true that C# uses iterative implementation of QuickSort algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. C# moved away from QuickSort to IntrospectiveSort, as also your link shows. You can see the comments and compatibility support at the [`Sort`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2300) source code.
2. The code you refer to is recursive. Near the end of the loop is a recursive call:

   ```
   private void IntroSort(int lo, int hi, int depthLimit)
   {
       while (hi > lo)
       {
           int partitionSize = hi - lo + 1;
           if (partitionSize <= IntrospectiveSortUtilities.IntrosortSizeThreshold)
           {
               // ... 
               InsertionSort(lo, hi);
               return;
           }
           // ...
           int p = PickPivotAndPartition(lo, hi);
           IntroSort(p + 1, hi, depthLimit); // <--- recursive call
           hi = p - 1;
       }
   }
   ```

   The next iteration of the loop takes the *left* partition, and the recursive call takes the *right* partition.

Comment: The recursive call on the the right partition occurs before the loop back to take care of the left partition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am just wondering why they use recursive approach? I am asking because I often heard and listened that recursion is less performant than iterative approach.

Comment: Recursion is iteration is recursion anyway..?

Comment: Sorry, @flackoverstow, I don't understand what you want to say.